# Unable to use OptionParser and rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, watir, watir-webdriver, optionparser

I have a simple watir (web-driver) script which goes to google. But, I want to use option parser to set an argument in the cmd to select a browser. Below is my script:

```
require 'optparse'
require 'commandline/optionparser'
include CommandLine
require 'watir-webdriver'

describe 'Test google website' do

  before :all do

    options = {}

    opts = OptionParser.new do |opts|

      opts.on("--browser N",
        "Browser to execute test scripts") do |n|
        options[:browser] = n
        $b = n.to_s
      end
    end

    opts.parse! ARGV

    p options
  end

  describe 'The test website should be displayed' do

    it 'should go to google' do
      $ie = Watir::Browser.new($b)
      #go to test website
  $ie.goto("www.google.com")
    end
  end
end
```

Executing rspec ietest.rb  --browser firefox -f doc
just gives me invalid option, ietest is the name of my file. Any other intuitive ways of setting a browser through web driver, with out changing script code, would be welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot use rspec with `OptionParser` since the rspec executable itself parses its own options. You cannot "piggy back" your options on the rspec options.

If you must do something like this then use either a settings file (`spec_config.yml` or similar), or use an environment variable:

`BROWSER=firefox spec test_something.rb`

And then in your code you can use `ENV['BROWSER']` to retrieve the setting.

Answer (score 1):

Please, learn about RSpec because I am guessing you have no clue about it (just google it). There are no expectations and you are writing your functionality in it.

```
require 'optparse'
require 'commandline/optionparser'
include CommandLine
require 'watir-webdriver'

options = {}

opts = OptionParser.new do |opts|

opts.on("--browser N",
  "Browser to execute test scripts") do |n|
  options[:browser] = n
end

opts.parse! ARGV

p options

ie = Watir::Browser.new(options[:browser].to_s)
#go to test website
ie.goto("www.google.com")
```

That should work.

**EDIT:** If you want to test it do something like this:

```
def open_url_with_browser(url, browser = 'firefox')
  nav = Watir::Browser.new(browser)
  nav.goto(url)
end
```

Then you would test that method in a spec. Just stub `new`, and `goto` in different specs.

If you are still wondering why are you getting the invalid option is because you are passing `--browser` to `rspec`, not your script, as intended.

Comment: I know the code worked before but I wanted it to work with rspec, I know the rspec code that I wrote is bad but it was a simple test to see how I can use rspec and OptionParser. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Thanks again for the help, it looks like I'll use something like this then.